# Is there any reason to use NuGet for internal Visual Studio helper projects?

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

I'm new package management systems so I'm trying to understand where they are useful and where they are not.

My office has several Visual Studio helper projects that we use in various solutions. Right now we just reference the helper project within the product solution. Is there a benefit in using NuGet to package these helper projects? At most, we have 5 to 10 developers on our team at any one time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how often your common projects change, whether you need to keep more then one versions of the project for other or not. For me I have found the following:

### Pros:

- If you need keep more than one version of common project, it's make
  your life much more easy.
- It supports same libraries for different frameworks in one package.
- Your product solutions have less projects, so VisualStudio and Resharper works faster.
- It disciplines your    team to write unit-tests, because test common project by unit-tests much more easy then functionally in an end product.

### Cons:

- If you need often update your common projects, it can be annoying.
  But you can setup CI to do it for you.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable info. I found a book called "Pro NuGet" on Safari books online which gives insight on how to implement this as well.